# Azure SAS token for specific tables

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I want to create SAS token for Azure storage account, which has Read permissions on TableA & TableB.

Is that possible with current storage client library?

Answer (score 1):

As of today it is not possible to create one SAS token for 2 tables. You would either need to create SAS token for each table separately or create an Account SAS which will give access to all tables.

Comment: And limit the account SAS to the Table service only